# what is getRepositoryToken in nestjs typeorm and when to use it?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

The docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#testing) are as below:

> When it comes to unit testing an application, we usually want to avoid
> making a database connection, keeping our test suites independent and
> their execution process as fast as possible. But our classes might
> depend on repositories that are pulled from the connection instance.
> How do we handle that? The solution is to create mock repositories. In
> order to achieve that, we set up custom providers. Each registered
> repository is automatically represented by a Repository
> token, where EntityName is the name of your entity class.
>
> The @nestjs/typeorm package exposes the getRepositoryToken() function
> which returns a prepared token based on a given entity.

What does that even mean? Autocomplete docs just give the signature with no explanation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`getRepositoryToken()` is a helper method that allows you to get the same injection token that `@InjectRepository()` returns. This is useful when it comes to tests so that you can define a custom provider that has a matching token for the DI resolution, and so you can provide a mock of the `Repository` methods without the need to actually talk to the database. So for example, if you have

```js
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Foo) private readonly fooRepo: Repository<Foo>) {}

}
```

In your test you can add the provider

```js
{
  provide: getRepositoryToken(Foo),
  useValue: {
    find: jest.fn(),
    insert: jest.fn(),
  },
}
```

And now you've got a mock injectable provider for the `Repository`.

The biggest reason that things have to be done this way is because typescript doesn't reflect generic classes, it only reflects `Repository`, and if Nest tries to figure out which repository you mean to inject, with just that name (`Repository`) it's most likely going to get it wrong and inject the wrong class. Using `@InjectRepsitory()` allows for setting the proper injection token.

Comment: So let me see if I understand your answer correctly. This is specifically used when mocking and testing the service or thing that calls the injected repository? So in some cases I've seen where getRepository is not used, but I think in those cases it is only testing the repository directly and not the service calling the repository method?

Comment: Sounds about right. You could also use the `getRepositoryToken()` to properly inject the repository into a `useFactory` method for asynchronous registration of modules

Comment: Love your DND app btw. :) 

I'm still a bit curious about the difference in the end result. In practice, I see it still works without the getRespositoryToken method even when testing the above scenario, and I don't see any issues.

Comment: I'd probably have to see how you're testing things. [This repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) has a lot of different tests, and includes tests for typeorm, mongoose, and sequelize. None of them connect to a database during unit tests, so a database connection is not needed during them.

Comment: but if i need to reset the mock of `find` and insert between each test it can be done in this approach?

Comment: @MatanTubul you should be able to get the repository in the initial `beforeAll` using the `getRepositoryToken()` and then in an `afterEach` you can reset each method as necessary. Or just use `jest.resetAllMocks()`