# How database connection internally work in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, singleton, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using `typeorm` to connect to database in `nestjs`. I am using `Repository` and `Connection`.
What I want to know is how connection and repository works internally. In nestjs, default scope is singleton. I understand that using `@InjectRepository(),` `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` and  `@InjectConnection()` means inject token. Since default scope is singleton, it works like singleton. However, every request must use different db connection(db connection pool). How it works?? Can someone explain how this works internally? Thanks!!

```js
import {  Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection, InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Food } from './entities/food.entity';
import { Repository, Connection } from 'typeorm';


@Injectable()
export class FoodsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Food)
    private readonly foodRepository: Repository<Food>,
    @InjectConnection()
    private connection: Connection,
  ) {}
}
```

foods.service.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FoodsService } from './foods.service';
import { FoodsController } from './foods.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Food } from './entities/food.entity';
import { FoodCategory } from './entities/food-category.entity';
import { FoodImage } from './entities/food-image.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Food, FoodImage, FoodCategory]),
  ],
  controllers: [FoodsController],
  providers: [FoodsService],
})
export class FoodsModule {}
```

foods.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

[I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938257/how-does-injectrepository-work-internally-in-nestjs/65941047#65941047) [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570680/what-is-getrepositorytoken-in-nestjs-typeorm-and-when-to-use-it/65570733#65570733) of answers that go into some of the mechanics of how the TypeORM package for Nest works. If you want to make you're repositories `REQUEST` scoped, and the connection `REQUEST` scoped, you can inject `REQUEST` into your configuration factory. Something like

```js
TypeormModule.forRootASync({
  inject: [REQUEST, COnfigService],
  useFactory: (req, config) => returnedConfigObjectFromConfigAndRequest
})
```

This will make every `@InjectRepository()` and **every** class that uses the database `REQUEST` scoped as well (bubbling up to the controller), just be sure you are aware of what this means for performance and do some benchmarking around it.

Comment: What I want to know is how @InjectRepository() internally works with database connection. 
In my opinion, if @InjectRepository() is singleton and connect direct with database connection, all request is using one database connection object(pool object). However I think this doesn't make sense. 
I heard that in java spring, object which contains metadata is singleton and object which directly connect with database or database connection pool is not a singleton.
Thanks!!

Comment: BY default it's all singleton. There's a connection pool that the repositories make use of. You'd need to look more into TypeORM's `getRepository()` method to see how that pool is used. `@InjectRepository()` is pretty much a custom provider that does `connection.getRepository()` for you

Comment: I don't know if I understood it well.
If there is a client A and a client B. For example, if A makes a request to a food repository and B also makes a request to the same repository, but the query requested by A takes a long time, if it is a singleton, do client B have to wait until request by A is done? Thanks!!